# Angular 9 - Material Date Picker - Set UTC

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs, moment-timezone

I've seen several posts here on Stack Overflow but none of the solutions proposed seem to be working with Angular 9.

What I'm trying to do is basic, set my Angular Material Calendar to display dates only in UTC.

For instance:

`this.form.controls['calendar'].setValue(new Date(1588291200000));`

which returns: **4/30/2020**

I want the calendar to display the date as **5/01/2020**.

I've tried using moment.js and followed the instruction on this link: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-locale-code but the date still shows as **4/30/2020** also tried every link on StackOverflow and Github that I could find and nothing.

I found this StackBlitz, which seems to be working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vesksm?file=app%2Fdatepicker-moment-example.ts but the application is using Angular 7, not good.

This is a huge problem because the dates are stored in UTC (GMT0) in the database, and when I load then in the frontend the calendar changes everything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you not take the local date then get the utc date to send/store in the server? Is it possible that 05/01 in utc is 04/30 in Los Angeles? If someone using your application in Los Angeles sets the date for whatever to happen on 04/30 their time, should it happen on 05/01 their time or 04/30 their time? The goal would be to show the utc time stored in the database in the date picker in the month day that is appropriate for that users zone/locale right?

Comment: Yes. It should be UTC both ways. The DB record looks like this:  *2020-05-01 00:00:00.000 +0000* but when I import in the front-end it shows like: *4/30/2020*

Comment: Disregard angular material for a second, this is more about what a 05/01 utc date should appear as for a user in somewhere like Los Angeles. Even just checking what is displayed for that utc timestamp as a new date in your browser dev console.

Comment: For instance: 
`let dt = new Date(1588291200000);` 
`console.log('dt raw', dt); // 04/30/2020 (not what I want)` 
`console.log('dt utc', dt.toUTCString()); // 05/01/2020 (what I want) `

Comment: Wait is that May 1 2020 0:00 value the same in central standard time? Is the same in Moscow? Is it the same in India? What happens if you take the value from the date picker and execute toUTCStrjng against it?

Comment: I use this: https://www.epochconverter.com/ to check conversion.

Comment: By being UTC/GMT0 it would be the same Datetime all over the world. That's what I want!

Comment: The `dt.toUTCString())` works fine but it returns a string and I can't fetch it back to the calendar. Also If I create a date Object with the date that I want the calendar will convert it back to the browser local timezone, I don't want local timezone. I wan't a fixed timezone for the calendar.

Comment: Okay sure, but the users choose a date based on utc? How do they know what their local date offset is compared to the utc date? I’ll stop after this, but when I use an event calendar to say my birthday is on 04/30, that may be 05/01 utc but still really is 04/30 for Chicago or whatever. I’d be upset if my friends also in Chicago where shown 05/01. Don’t worry I’m backing away.

Comment: At the moment the user chose date based on its local timezone, I don't want this. So whenever the record hits the database I convert it back to UTC/GMT0 because I can't set the calendar to UTC / GMT0 in Angular. All I want is to have UTC / GMT 0 calendar for my whole application, no local timezone!

Comment: Just want to point out one thing to hopefully help. If you review the the following example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1vhike . The timestamp `1588291200000` resolves to `Thu Apr 30 2020 18:00:00 GMT-0600`.  `new Date('Thu Apr 30 2020 18:00:00 GMT-0600').toUTCString()` resolves to `Fri, 01 May 2020 00:00:00 GMT`. `console.log(new Date(this.date.value).toUTCString() === new Date(1588291200000).toUTCString()) // true`. You can take the string value emitted from the datepicker and put it into `new Date()` and apply `toUTCString()`.

Comment: Yes but the problem remains the same because the calendar won't accept a string as a valid date. It always converts all the dates to the local timezone, the problem is the calendar.

Comment: @yaKay im facing same issue, have you found solution ?